# How to extract data from a list with addtional spaces in between them in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, text, text-files

The code is trying to extract from a file: (format: group, team, val1, val2). However, some results are correct if there is no additional space and produces wrong result in lines with additional spaces in between.

```
data = {}
with open('source.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        print ("this is the line data: ", line)
        
        needed = line.split()[0:2]
        print ("this is what i need: ", needed)
```

source.txt #-- format: group, team, val1, val2

```
alpha diehard group 1 54,00.01
bravo nevermindteam 3 500,000.00
charlie team ultimatum 1 27,722.29 ($250.45)
charlie team ultimatum 10 252,336,733.383 ($492.06)
delta beyond-imagination 2 11 ($10)
echo double doubt 5 143,299.00 ($101)
echo double doubt 8 145,300 ($125.01)
falcon revengers 3 0.1234
falcon revengers 5 9.19
lima almost done 6 45.00181 ($38.9)
romeo ontheway home 12 980
```

I am trying to just extract the values before val1. #-- group, team

```
alpha diehard group
bravo nevermindteam
charlie team ultimatum
delta beyond-imagination
echo double doubt
falcon revengers
lima almost done
romeo ontheway home
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use regex.

```
import regex as re
with open('source.txt') as f:
   for line in f:
       found = re.search("(.*?)\d", line)
       needed = found.group(1).split()[0:3]
       print(needed)
```

Output:

```
['alpha', 'diehard', 'group']
['bravo', 'nevermindteam']
['charlie', 'team', 'ultimatum']
['charlie', 'team', 'ultimatum']
['delta', 'beyond-imagination']
['echo', 'double', 'doubt']
['echo', 'double', 'doubt']
['falcon', 'revengers']
['falcon', 'revengers']
['lima', 'almost', 'done']
['romeo', 'ontheway', 'home']
```

Comment: BTW, if the name of group or team contains a digit, you will need to come up with a better regex.

Answer (score 2):

Try with

```
with open('source.txt') as f:
   for line in f:
       new_line = ' '.join(filter(lambda s: s.isalpha() , l.split(' ')))
       print(new_line)
```

The code is sensible to the amount of white spaces.

With regex

```
import regex

with open('source.txt', 'r') as f:
    text = re.sub(r'[0-9|,|\.|\(|\)|\$|\s]+\n', '\n', f.read()+'\n', re.M)
```

Comment: still getting line with val1 in it.

Comment: yes I notice that is bugged! I will check it out, sorry!

Comment: @rbutrnz added filter to check only alphabetic characters

Comment: It works as well without checking the 1st character of the string, directly on the full string: ```s.isalpha()```

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I did it, basically iterate through all the words and stop when you hit a numeric:

```
data = {}
with open('source.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        print ("this is the line data: ", line)
        
        split_line = line.split()
        for i in range (len(split_line)):
            if split_line[i].isnumeric():
                break
        
        needed = split_line[0:i]
        
        print ("this is what i need: ", needed)
```